# sections over compact subsets extend to global?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose S is a sheaf (of abelian groups, say) over a space X. Is there a name for the property: (*) every continuous section over a compact subset K of X extends to a global section? Note that X need not be T_2 etc.

If we replace "compact" by "closed" then we have a "soft" sheaf

If we replace "compact" by "open" we have a "flabby" sheaf

Is there a standard term used in the compact case?

Example: a sheaf over a 0-dimensional space has this property *, but is not necessarily fine or flabby.

Comment: If you replace "compact" by "closed", you obtain a "soft" sheaf, not a "fine" sheaf.  ( Fine is a stronger notion: fine $\Rightarrow$ soft.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard term is "c-soft". (See Glen Bredon's book *Sheaf theory*, for example.)